Is a flat universe the most interesting?
Suppose we would like a universe to expand at an optimal rate, defined so that in any time frame each particle on average undergoes an approximately constant number of interactions (same as today) before it potentially acquires another RT of free energy due to the expansion of space. Is such a universe a flat spacetime, or is it measurably different?
Rationale: "Interesting" seems hard to define, but we know what is not interesting: when there is only one particle in the observable universe ('Big Rip'), or when there is no heat sink to provide free energy by increasing the entropy of particles in space ('heat death').  There have been many eras of the universe with drastically different durations and physical distances, dominated by different types of physics, yet in each of them a vast number of important events have occurred.  In this question I'm clumsily reaching for the notion of how the universe would need to expand so that there is, for example, a future era when neutrinos form 'nuggets' and undergo some sort of interesting 'neutrino chemistry' with a large number of non-equilibrium reactions, and perhaps further eras after that.  If there is a different way to ask a question to answer that better approaches that, please advise.  Also, I realize any such number would be have to be an average, considering cosmic inflation would have thrown in a mite bit of variation. :)

Neutrinos will probably never do that. We’re mostly out of the interesting age of cosmological physics; the most interesting interactions we’ll see are probably between black holes and black holes (or our probes and black holes, hopefully someday).

@controlgroup - I'd be interested what you've seen about the plausibility of "neutrino chemistry".  There were a few things about 'neutrino nuggets' a long time back now and I don't know where the expert opinion stands now about it.  Also, when you say "never", do you mean the aleph-null kind of never?  An old, cold universe could take a really, really long time to do anything, but that's OK -- logs go all the way up. :)

I’ve never read anything about neutrino chemistry, but their mass is so low - mass-energy is something like less than 0.8 eV so the mass is less than $10^{-35}$ kg ($\approx10^{-5}$ electron masses). Having absolutely any energy at all, which is always due to quantum fluctuation, means that neutrinos will be zipping around at near-lightspeed, so formation of neutrino structures would be nearly impossible and would take a temperature so low that I’d bet Universal expansion would get in the way and reduce the overall neutrino density. Plus, they don’t have a strong attractive force to bind them.

There are many things on Arxiv about neutrino-neutrino refraction, such as this paper; alas, I lack the background to make sense out of it.  But I see elastic collision and thermalization.  If neutrinos act like a gas, with a temperature, then allowing that gas to expand should cool it off like any other gas, I think.  So I think they should eventually become non-relativistic, at least, and in that paper is probably the basis for some chemistry.

Measurements of the large scale structure of the visible universe are consistent with spacetime being flat. But there is some uncertainty. It could be slightly curved.
Assume the part of the universe beyond where we can see is much the same as what we can see. This may or may not be true. If it is, the diameter of a flat universe would be infinite. The diameter of a universe with the maximum curvature consistent with what we measure would have a diameter $500$ times the visible universe. See this Don Lincoln video for more - What really happened at the Big Bang?
